# Are Microwave Ovens Harmful?

Tags: nutrition, microwaves

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can microwave ovens give you cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/552/can-microwave-ovens-give-you-cancer)

I was handed a leaflet today by a man in a bumble-bee costume. Here's an excerpt:

> **Cook with Love. but without a Microwave Oven**
>
> ln cellular telecommunication microwave radiation causes irreversible damages in man and nature. The effects of microwave radiation are even more severe when it comes to the microwave oven. You and your family are not only exposed to the leakage radiation, which penetrates concrete walls and can extend far into other rooms and flats, you also take in food with a completely destroyed molecular structure. Our immune system identifies such molecular structures as foreign bodies and reacts in the same way as it does in the early stages of a cancerous process.

Do microwave ovens leak harmful radiation? Does eating microwaved food increase my risk of developing cancer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can microwave ovens give you cancer?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/552/can-microwave-ovens-give-you-cancer) and [Is food cooked in a microwave oven considered harmful for the health?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/528/is-food-cooked-in-a-microwave-oven-considered-harmful-for-the-health)

Comment: Possibly.  If thrown fast enough.