# Is the microwave bad for heating baby food?

Tags: nutrition, environmental-health, children, microwaves

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is food cooked in a microwave oven considered harmful for the health?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/528/is-food-cooked-in-a-microwave-oven-considered-harmful-for-the-health)

I am well aware that there are concerns about "hot spots" (small areas which are hotter than others that are produced in the microwave) when heating something by microwave, but until I read [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/528/is-food-cooked-in-a-microwave-oven-considered-harmful-for-the-health), I was under the impression that heating food (or formula/milk) in a microwave had adverse nutritional effects. It seems that heating it until it is lukewarm and then using hot water for the remainder would actually be more effective.

- Aside from the "hot spots" issue, is there any detriment to microwaving a bottle?

Comment: Well, as a single datapoint, once I tried to warm a baby bottle, the kind that's open on the bottom and had a plastic liner. So then I pointed it away from myself and gave it a shake. Pow! The liner popped and gave me 2nd-degree burns on my chest!

Comment: I've seen some kid-oriented science experiments using heat-sensitive color-changing substances that provide evidence hot/cold spots do exist - though I don't know if / how long they'd persist in low-viscosity liquid. Edit: http://www.puttyworld.com/usethputofis.html uses color-changing putty to find cold spots in a microwave, and measure the distance between them to estimate the speed of light.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig If you made that an answer, I would definitely +1 it

Comment: If you separated the claims into separate questions, I'd feel comfortable posting it as an answer. As it is, it really says nothing about the safety of baby food - and it's hardly a site I'd turn to for serious scientific information.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig That makes sense, so I created another question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/are-microwave-hot-spots-real which you should answer!

Comment: I would just make sure you heat it in a BPA & phthalate free type of plastic, or use a glass bottle.

Comment: Maybe this is a better question for the Parenting SE?  The nutritional aspects have already been addressed here.

Comment: I suppose that it wouldn't matter much for formula, but it might be worth reiterating DO NOT MICROWAVE WATER IN A SMOOTH GLASS CONTAINER.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim I've done that before. It is only dangerous if you don't know what you're doing and you end up over-heating the water. It is perfectly safe otherwise.

Comment: O_o um....boom?

Comment: Since separating the claims, this has become a duplicate.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Not at all, you just *need to know what you're doing*. I also know how to hard-boil eggs in the microwave without them exploding.

Comment: And you think the average litigious consumer will take the time to do this? You have far more faith in humanity than I do...

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Not at all. I think that the average consumer will end up getting a severe burn. That said, it is *possible* to microwave fluids in the microwave with no negative effects.

Comment: Oh yes, agreed. Just not safe for average end users.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim I completely agree.