# Do harmful chemicals migrate from the container into the food if you microwave the food in a plastic container?

Tags: nutrition, chemistry, microwaves

In a comment to the best answer to question [582](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/528/is-food-cooked-in-a-microwave-oven-harmful-for-the-health), [Muhd](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/6185/muhd) writes: "*I would add that it is also unhealthy if you microwave in something that is not microwave safe as toxic chemicals could migrate into the food from the container (e.g. from most plastics).*"

Is there any evidence for this?
Are some plastics more dangerous than others?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/does-regularly-drinking-from-a-plastic-container-cause-cancer

Answer (score 8):

## No

Microwaved plastics do not cause cancer.

> **Can I microwave food in plastic containers or covered in plastic film?**
> There is no scientific evidence that microwaving food in plastic containers or wrapped in clingfilm can affect the risk of cancer.

—[Plastic bottles - Cancer Research UK](http://info.cancerresearchuk.org/healthyliving/cancercontroversies/Plasticbottles/)

> **Claim**: Research has proved that microwaving foods in plastic containers releases cancer-causing agents into the foods.
> **Status**: False.

—[Plastic-Tac-Toe - Snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/medical/toxins/cookplastic.asp)

> **Myth: Microwaving plastic containers and wraps releases harmful, cancer-causing substances into food.**
>
> Fact: Microwave-safe plastic containers and wraps are safe to use in the microwave.

—[Cancer causes: Popular myths about the causes of cancer - Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/cancer-causes/CA00085)

Comment: You had me till that third quote.  "Microwave-safe plastic containers" would seem to imply that there are "microwave-unsafe" plastic containers as well.

Comment: @Kyralessa: "Microwave-safe" plastics are designed not to melt in the microwave.  It has nothing to do with what's being discussed here.

Comment: The question seems to ask mainly about toxicity but your answer focuses only on cancer.  There are a lot of ways for something to be toxic without having to cause cancer.

Comment: "Microwave-safe plastic" is referring to, in my interpretation, the ability of the container to resist the heat (and survive the process unscathed), as much as it is referring to the safety of the consumer. This makes complete sense when you see a non-microwave-safe plastic container warp and melt after one burst in the microwave.